# using underscore to add items to a html table with jquery

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I found that I can add table to my table with

```
$('#mytable').append("<tr><td>").text("yo").append("</td></tr>");
```

but if I do that multiple times like so:

```
$('#mytable').append("<tr><td>").text("yo1").append("</td></tr>");
$('#mytable').append("<tr><td>").text("yo2").append("</td></tr>");
```

It ends up just using the last one, "yo2."  Is there a way to use underscore to iterate through my backbone model to insert rows into a html table dynamically.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `template` and `each` methods, http://underscorejs.org/#template

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your multiple `append` and `text` calls are failing because they can't chain like that. Since you want to use Backbone and underscore, what you can do is use `_.each` ([docs](http://underscorejs.org/#each)) to iterate through your attributes and append them to your table. Like this:

```
var TableModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        "foo": "foo",
        "bar": "bar",
        "blah": "blah"
    }
});

var TableView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#mytable',
    initialize: function() {
    },
    render: function() {
        _.each(this.model.attributes, function(val, key) {
            var row = "<tr><td>" + val + "</td></tr>";
            $('#mytable').append(row);
        });
        return this;
    }
});

var newModel = new TableModel();
var modelView = new TableView({model: newModel});
modelView.render();
```

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ctasims/a8rsE/2/), working as intended. I'm just creating a dummy model and view. In the view's `render()` function I'm iterating over the models and appending each, inside a row, to the table.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with backbone, but if you can store your values in an array you can do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var values = ['yo', 'yo2'],
    text = [];

    for(i=0;i<values.length;i++){
        text.push("<tr><td>"+values[i]+"</td></tr>");
    }
    $('#myTable').append(text.join(""));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use backbone, you can use underscore/lodash template engine and convert data to html-code like this:

```
var data = ['yo1', 'yo2'];
var templ = "<tr><td><%=value%></td></tr>";
var rows = _.map(data, function(item) { return _.template(templ, {value: item}); });
var html = rows.join('');
$('#mytable').empty().append(html);
```